# Want to join dataframe based on two columns in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark in databricks.
I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.
I want to left join df1 with df2. However based on condition on df2's columns.

> From df1, it checks if df1.ID is present in df2.A, if it is present, it takes the row value, else if it is Null, then it checks df2.B, if it is same as df.ID, it keeps it.

df1

```
| ID       | 
| -------- | 
| aaa      | 
| bbb      | 
| ccc      | 
| ddd      | 
| eee      |
```

df2

```
|     A    |     B    |     C    |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| aaa      |    aaa   | 23       |
| eee      |    bbb   | 32       |
| Null     |    ccc   | 45       |
| Null     |    ddd   | 76       |
```

Output

```
| ID       |      A    |     B    |     C    |
| -------- | --------  | -------- | -------- | 
| aaa      | aaa       |    aaa   | 23       |
| bbb      |           |          |          |
| ccc      | Null      |    ccc   | 45       | 
| ddd      | Null      |    ddd   | 76       | 
| eee      |  eee      |    bbb   | 32       |
```

I tried following but it is not giving me correct results:

```
join_conditions = [
    df1.ID == df2.A,
    (df1.ID  == df2.B) | (df2.A.isNull())
]

df3 = df1.join(df2, join_conditions,"left")
```

Comment: this condition `(df1.ID  == df2.B) | (df2.A.isNull())` I offten see refered in documentation or other tutorials as used in a specific sentence indexing dataframe, you could try `df1[(df1.ID  == df2.B) | (df2.A.isNull())]` or `df2`, `|` **`OR`** operator is used inside brackets `[]` no outside, i certainly not sure what your program does but you probably would need to replace this conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditions `df2.A.isNotNull() & (df1.ID == df2.A)` and `df2.A.isNull() & (df1.ID == df2.B)` and separate them with `|`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["aaa"],["bbb"],["ccc"],["ddd"],["eee"]], schema=["ID"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["aaa","aaa","23"],["eee","bbb","32"],[None,"ccc","45"],[None,"ddd","76"]], schema=["A","B","C"])

result_df = df1.join(df2,
                     (
                         (df2.A.isNotNull() & (df1.ID == df2.A))
                         |
                         (df2.A.isNull() & (df1.ID == df2.B))
                     ),
                     how="left"
                     )

result_df.show()
+---+----+----+----+
| ID|   A|   B|   C|
+---+----+----+----+
|aaa| aaa| aaa|  23|
|bbb|null|null|null|
|ccc|null| ccc|  45|
|ddd|null| ddd|  76|
|eee| eee| bbb|  32|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?